# MySQL archival of a live production database table

Tags: mysql, rds

I need a proper strategy to archive a live production table.

This table has a lot of inserts happening on it(close to 1000 inserts per minute). It is a myisam table and it has a key column with an auto incremented numeric value.

1. I need to move data older than Jan 01 to a new archive table
2. Inserts should not get affected.

The data is hosted on an RDS instance in Amazon.

Please help!

**EDIT:** 
The table structure is:

> CREATE TABLE `data` (
>     `id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>     `id_1` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
>     `id_2` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
>     `timestamp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
>     `status_code` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
>     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
>     UNIQUE KEY `check_2` (`id_1`,`id_2`,`timestamp`,`status_code`),
>     KEY `account_id_3` (`id_1`,`timestamp`)
>   ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=75996470 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

In addition to the above fields, there are about 30 more fields in this table which can accept NULL values.

Comment: Well, could you provide data structure definition / table definition ?

Comment: HAL9000: I ve added the table structure